# vsphere cannot complete login due to an incorrect user name or password

Tags: passwords, authentication, esxi, vmware-server, vsphere

When I try to login to my vsphere environment, I get the following error: "Cannot complete login due to an incorrect user name or password." I am certain that I am using the correct login information because I was successful before with the same information. I have checked with my co-workers and they tell me they have not changed the password. I am using vmware vsphere client 5.5. Just FYI, I'm still learning how to use vsphere.

Does anyone know of a work-around or any other way I can get into my environment without losing any VMs or data?

Comment: What version of ESXi/vCenter? If you did not implement any changes - your certificates on vCenter/PSC might have expired...that you can easily check with looking at the certificate in the browser on the lock icon.

Comment: The version of vCenter is 5.5.0. I've spoken to my supervisor and he says that we only use a self sign certificate. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me with this.

Comment: well, with the version 5.5.0 already being out of support I would bet that those self-signed certs are expired. but that is something you need to check and confirm. and you probably should get to at least 6.5 with latest updates if your HW is supported.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's a work around to this issue. Thank you for help. Once I get this figured out, I'll post a resolution, unless someone else posts it first.

Comment: Well, I did not understand your comment. the answer "we are using self signed certificates" does not answer my question about the expiry date on them. if they are expired - you will not be able to log in. Certificate management in 5.5 is not the best - to say it mildly, but does not mean it can't be done. You could try [Certificate Manager for vCenter Server Appliance 5.5](https://flings.vmware.com/certificate-manager-for-vcenter-server-appliance-5-5). A VMware fling - meaning - you can't get support for it. So before you do anything, take snapshots.

Comment: well, you could connect to the ESXi with the fat client. use root and the set password. all VMs should be running. "Loosing" vCenter does not stop VMs.

Comment: All of my VMs are still running. I'm not too worried about that part. I'm going to take your advice and update to version 6. I also contacted VMware, so hopefully they will offer some help.

Comment: VMware will help if you have a valid support contract/licence. to update to 6 you will need new license keys. And I would suggest to update to 6.7 if your third party add ons will allow it.

Comment: I'm in contact with support now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be an expiration of the administrator profile and the root profile as well. I spent about an hour on the phone with a vmware tech to watch him go through the whole process. I wish I could've kept notes but he was going too fast. I was able to work it out with the help of vmware. I still need to upgrade the software to at least version 6.5 just to keep support handy.